# Problem with zend_acl zend_auth and helper url (Zend Framework)

Tags: zend-framework, zend-auth

Friends.
I put together a site with Zend_Acl and Zend_Auth and works perfect.
The problem comes when I enter a page is not permitted and the site returns to the index page, here are the urls that armed with the helper url zend framework are changed.

url(array('module' => 'moduno', 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index'));?>">moduno

This url when return after the rejection, change your address.
Any solution?

Thanks friends.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include this resources and role in your acl file? 
Check your code if u returned any function in that controller before an action